# want to change list elements using radiobutton

Tags: list, tkinter, radio-button, python-3.3

I have a list (elenco) and I want to change its elements when I click on a radiobutton, but i always obtain the same list

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

el1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
el2 = [2, 2, 3, 4, 5]

elenco = []

def E(e):
    elenco = e
    return elenco

print (elenco)

radio1 = Radiobutton (text = 'r1', value = 1, command = lambda: E (el1)).pack()
radio2 = Radiobutton (text = 'r2', value = 2, command = lambda: E (el2)).pack()

print(elenco)

root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: I post here all the new code. I'm rewriting all the program, because I had some problems with the old code.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list3 = [7, 8, 9]

class mainWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    # Canvas on which buttons will be put:
        mainCanvas = Canvas (self, height = 650, width = 900, scrollregion = (0, 0, 900, 6000), bg = 'white')

    # Scrollbar to see all buttons (they could me also more then 60):
        sbar = Scrollbar(self, command = mainCanvas.yview)

        mainCanvas.config(yscrollcommand = sbar.set)              
        sbar.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)                    
        mainCanvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)


    #radiobuttons from which I'll choose the list
        radio1 = Radiobutton(self, text = 'lis1', value = 1).place (x = 920, y = 150) 
        radio2 = Radiobutton(self, text = 'lis2', value = 2).place (x = 920, y = 170)
        radio3 = Radiobutton(self, text = 'lis3', value = 3).place (x = 920, y = 190)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("main")
    root.geometry("1130x650+100+10")
    app = mainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

In this code there aren't buttons, but if you run the program you will see a white canvas, they will be there. There will also be a EntryBox where you will be able to write the element (-s) name (or part of it) and you will be given the buttons that correspond to that name. But if you want to switch by a list to another? so, if I want the button for the element4 which is in the second list and not in the first one? it seems useless, but in fact there will be 720 elements in the main list, and all the other lists will be part of that one. Lists correspond to regions, and the main list is the one with all them. So, if I want some elements starting with letter "a" but I want it from a particular list (region) and not from everywhere?

If you have better ideas then choose the list by the radiobutton, I'll use it. My problem is to move by a list to another

Comment: Your program in total is messy. The function and the callback commands are nonsense. I wrote it in a little different way. Looking forward for your feedback.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to say.
"If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you." -http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to get:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]

buttonvar = IntVar()
buttonvar.set(' ')

def changeList():
    mainList = []
    if buttonvar.get() == 0:
        mainList = list1
        print(mainList)
    else:
        mainList = list2
        print(mainList)

rb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="List 1",
                  variable=buttonvar, value=0, command=changeList)
rb1.pack()

rb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="List 2",
                  variable=buttonvar, value=1, command=changeList)
rb2.pack()
```

?
P.S.: This answer of mine is based on @vladi's edit and comment: "For exemple: the list is empty, I click on button1, the list becomes [1,2,3], then I click on button 3 and I obtain [7,8,9]"

Comment: Ok, I'll try it... I hope it works... The mainlist will change also out of the function or it will remain as it was before? For now thanks... Sorry for all the problems I gave you. As I test the code I'll say you

Comment: @vladi It's pleasure to help others! Still looking forward to hear from you. Please, if any answer solves your problem, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]

buttonvar = IntVar()
buttonvar.set(' ')

def changeList():
    if buttonvar.get() == 0:
        print(list1)
    else:
        print(list2)

rb1 = Radiobutton(root, text='r1',
                  variable=buttonvar, value=0, command=changeList)
rb1.pack()

rb2 = Radiobutton(root, text='r2',
                 variable=buttonvar, value=1, command=changeList)
rb2.pack()
```

Basically, I used a variable (`buttonvar`) for radiobuttons, and changed lambda functions to a normal function (`changeList`) and used a condition (`if-else`) inside that function that prints a list on every radiobutton click depending on the variable values (`0` or `1`). I also set `buttonvar` to `' '`, so when you start the program none of the radiobuttons will be selected. Other than this I only changed some of the variables cos I don't know, I just thought my new variables would look better (LOL!).

Comment: this answer would be better if you described what you did differently. Otherwise the reader is required to compare your code line-by-line with the original to see what's different.

Comment: @ ParvizKarimli Oh! Thanks for the answer but maybe I didn't explained good what I wanted. When the program runs I need it to have a list already chosen (it was the list elenco), but during the program, in any moment, I must have the possibility to change list and choose another one by click on the button...  Do you think I have to use "trace"? If yes, how?

Comment: @vladi you are welcome! If the answer above solves the problem, please accept it, so others will know that this question has already been answered and accepted when they visit this page.

Comment: @vladi where in the program and how would you use "trace"?

Comment: @Parviz I will explain you better what I need, because probably I explained it bad. I have a program that uses a list to create buttons (which, when clicked open a new window with other infos). It all works, but I want to put the possibility to choose the list. So if I have 5 lists, and I run the program it uses one of them, how can I do to choose the second one by pushing the radiobutton? Don't know if you will undersyand cause my english isn't the best... If you want I can post all the code

Comment: @vladi do you want to control the process only by one radiobutton?

Comment: @Parviz If you want I can add 10 of them hahah it's not a problem, but I don't know how to do. When I'll be at home I'll send you the code, it will take less then an hour I think... I'll be great if you help me, and thanks for the attention and help you gave me to this moment

Comment: @vladi you said: "by pushing the radiobutton", so I thought you are talking about a specific radiobutton, that is why I asked.

Comment: @Parviz No, i meant that when I click on a radiobutton it returns me a list, me I click on another it changes again to another one and so on... Now I'll poste the code

Comment: @vladi please explain what you exactly want to get.

Comment: @vladi do you want only one list to be updated on button clicks?

Comment: @Parviz Yes.. I have to obtain a list. This list will be used to create buttons. What is into the list depends by which button I've clicked. For exemple: the list is empty, I click on button1, the list becomes [1,2,3], then I click on button 3 and I obtain [7,8,9] and so...